# Iron-Router: Can I target a specific nested template to display my loadingTemplate?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using iron-router in a meteor project. What I want to do is show my loadingTemplate only within a particular nested template on the page (i.e. the content area that uses the data my waitOn is waiting for), not in place of the whole page as happens with `Router.onBeforeAction('loading');`.

**Is it possible to do this using iron-router?**

My simplified code:

**layout.html**

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="foo">
    //bunch of intro text
        {{> bar}}
    //a big CTA
</template>

<template name="bar">
    {{this.something}}
</template>
```

What I want to do is replace the `bar` template with the loadingTemplate until the data is loaded. The rest of the page can render.
Here's the default way that, of course, shows loadingTemplate in place of the whole page (e.g. `foo'):

**router.js**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

//Router.onBeforeAction('loading'); //Future SO visitors: use this to show the loading template on all routes, if that's what you desire. I only want to show the loading template on one route.

this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    action: function () {
      if (this.ready()) // is there a short-hand version btw?
        this.render();
      else
        this.render('loading');
    },
    onBeforeAction: function () {
      //this.render('loading'); //shouldn't this be the short-hand version? Doesn't work.
    },
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('baz');
    },
    data: function () {
      return Baz.find();
    }
  });
```

If what I'm looking for isn't possible with iron-router, any suggested alternatives are most welcome. Thanks!

For future visitors, here are the iron-router [docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full credit to Geoffrey Booth for sending this in the right direction. The full technical answer to the original question follows. The short answer is yes, it IS possible to target specific nested templates using iron-router as Geoffrey mentioned. The more involved answer: there is likely a better alternative depending on your use case...see comments to Geoffrey's answer for a good discussion.

The full working code using the example in the original question:

The html

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> yield region='header'}}
  {{> yield region='body'}}
  {{> yield region='footer'}}
</template>

<template name="foo">
  //bunch of intro text
   {{> yield}}
  //a big CTA
</template>

<template name="bar">
  {{this.something}}
</template>
```

and the router

```
Router.onBeforeAction('loading');

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'bar',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    yieldTemplates: {
      'myHeader': {to: 'header'},
      'myFooter': {to: 'footer'},
      'foo': {to: 'body'}
    },
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('baz');
    },
    data: function () {
      return Baz.find();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Read the section in the docs called [Using a Layout with Yields](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#using-a-layout-with-yields). Basically what you need to do is add a few more yields to your layout template, and define other sub-templates to go into them. The 'loading' template will load only in the main yield.

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> yield region='header'}}
  {{> yield}}
  {{> yield region='footer'}}
</template>
```

and

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'foo',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout', // This and the following two can also be defined
    loadingTemplate: 'loading', // in Router.configure like your code does
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    yieldTemplates: {
      'myHeader': {to: 'header'}, // You need to define the other templates
      'myFooter': {to: 'footer'} // that will be sent into other yields
    },
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('baz');
    },
    data: function () {
      return Baz.find();
    }
  });
});
```

The `action` and `onBeforeAction` parameters in your code are unnecessary; that’s what `waitOn` is doing.

Comment: How would I make sure the loading template yields only in the `bar` template? And thanks for the clarification re: action/onBeforeAction...very helpful.

Comment: A template is rendered in a yield; what do you mean by 'template yields only in the `bar` template?' You can control what goes where via the `yieldTemplates`, `loadingTemplate`, `notFoundTemplate` and `layoutTemplate` parameters (see my example above). The templates listed in `yieldTemplates` will go into the named yields specified; all others (loading, notFound, `home`) will go into the *main* yield, i.e. the one without a name (just `{{> yield}}`).

Comment: Your comment, "The 'loading' template will load only in the main yield" was helpful. In my case, I only want the 'loading' template to load only in the `bar` template, therefore that will be my main yield (`{{> yield}}`). That means I'll have to define everything else as regions. So in my example code, in the `layout` template I'd have to define the header and footer as regions, and then in the `foo` template I'd have to define `//...a bunch of intro text` and `//...a big CTA` as regions. Then I'd have to use `yieldTemplates` to yield the right templates int he right regions. That right?

Comment: I was afraid of that :( Seems the best option might be going outside iron-router for this one. Thanks for the help in understanding regions...much appreciated.

Comment: The alternative is to just use a template helper. Inside `foo`: `{{#if isReady}}{{> bar}}{{else}}Loading...{{/if}}` and create a helper `Template.foo.isReady = function () { return Baz.findOne() !== undefined; };` (or find some other way to determine if ready, such as assign the subscription to a global variable and have the helper call it i.e. `BazSubscription.ready()`).

Comment: Updated your answer to show the full working example (and to help future visitors). I couldn't get the template to show unless I included `//Router.onBeforeAction('loading');` though. Sample repo here: https://github.com/chadokruse/iron-router-sandbox.

Comment: Looks like the moderators rejected your edit; try posting it as a new answer?

Comment: Shame...your answer was right, just missing some detail. Mods, would appreciate feedback on why the edit was rejected (it was intended to simply fill in the missing detail).

Comment: I think there is a significant difference in that my version tells you to direct the main template and the loading template into the main yield, `{{> yield}}`, whereas your version doesn't have a main yield at all (you name all three yields, so they're all regions). Variations on a theme, but I think they *are* two different approaches/answers, as similar as they are. You were changing more than just fixing a few typos. Not to say that one is better than the other, either, they're just slightly different.

Comment: Really appreciate that clarification. Indeed, my use case was a deeply nested template, hence the need to focus the yield on a template deep within `<template name="layout">`...and realizing there are much better alternatives as you suggest. Thanks again.